# How to correctly apply soap on my back when bathing?

Tags: personal-care

I cannot apply soap on back properly when bathing, even though I'm a healthy adult.

This is a hectic work in order to clean my body. I have to wash my back properly too.

Is there any lifehack  to apply soap easily?

Answer (score 7):

Do you have a scrub or something like that with a long handle on it? Maybe you could attach one of these to the end of a "stick" and apply soap like that.

Comment: They actually call this a [back brush](https://www.google.com/search?q=back+brush&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS756US756&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-ofXd9vjaAhUPslMKHZ7dDqMQ_AUICygC&biw=1060&bih=929).  Perfect solution.

Comment: It's the [Micky Mouse](http://bp3.blogger.com/_7GF2kkMcTKc/R4FU5JGo9nI/AAAAAAAAJzo/T8QxEmbt9Lc/s1600-h/seal.bmp) technique! :)

Answer (score 5):

Use a Japanese shower cloth. They're long enough to hold with one hand above and one below the back so you can scrub the whole thing.

You can move your hands around and arch your back to scrub different parts, but you'll get everything, and better, you'll *know* you got everything.

As a bonus, you can use it as your showering cloth for your whole body, so you're not storing an extra thing in your shower.

[image: Three Japanese shower cloths in packaging]

Answer (score 3):

You have several options when it comes to back cleaning.

My preferred method is to lather up my hair and let the suds drip down my back while rinsing. I find I'm able to get pretty full coverage on my back with soap, and as long as I haven't been shirtless, this light stripping of oils is sufficient.

Similarly, soaking in a soapy bath may also prove sufficient to clean off an accumulation of skin oils.

However, if your back is particularly dirty you may need to employ some tools to scrub it.  As BrettFromLA suggests, the ideal tool is called a back brush.

Sans a back brush you could try draping washcloth over your shoulder and garbing the opposing ends with your hands in order to reach the areas you are otherwise unable to reach.